# Exposing custom custom UIKit events from custom UIKit controls to SwiftUI

Tags: event-handling, uikit, swiftui, combine

I have a custom UIKit control that has a custom event. Does anybody know how to expose this event to SwiftUI using the Combine framework?

I can render the control using Combine's UIViewRepresentable but cannot find a way to expose the custom events or the values changed by internal UIKit events to SwiftUI.

Here is a concrete example of this problem:

I am using this custom UIKit slider control (because it support multiple knobs/ values):

https://github.com/yonat/MultiSlider

It has a sliderChanged event which updates the current value. 
How do I expose this value to SwiftUI using Combine?

I cannot simply pass in a @ObservedObject because UIViewRepresentable does not allow this. I also cannot update a @Binding variable from the event handler because the UIKit event handlers are marked with  @objc  and it does not like it.

It appears to be a very common use case. I expected Apple to have a standard solution for this. However, I simply cannot find one that actually works for these types of scenarios. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 2):

I think, that this can be solution for your problem:

```
final class MultiSliderSwiftUI: UIViewRepresentable {
    private let valueChanged: ([CGFloat]) -> Void

    init(valueChanged: @escaping ([CGFloat]) -> Void) {
        self.valueChanged = valueChanged
    }

    func makeUIView(context: UIViewRepresentableContext<MultiSliderSwiftUI>) -> MultiSlider {
        let slider = MultiSlider()
        slider.addTarget(self, action: #selector(sliderChanged(_:)), for: .valueChanged)

        return slider
    }

    func updateUIView(_ uiView: MultiSlider, context: UIViewRepresentableContext<MultiSliderSwiftUI>) {

    }

    @objc func sliderChanged(_ slider: MultiSlider) {
        valueChanged(slider.value)
    }
}
```

If you don't like create `final class` for SwiftUI views, you can do it in this way:

```
struct MultiSliderSwiftUI: UIViewRepresentable {
    private let events: MultiSliderEvents

    init(valueChanged: @escaping ([CGFloat]) -> Void) {
        events = MultiSliderEvents(valueChanged: valueChanged)
    }

    func makeUIView(context: UIViewRepresentableContext<MultiSliderSwiftUI>) -> MultiSlider {
        let slider = MultiSlider()
        events.addEvents(for: slider)

        return slider
    }

    func updateUIView(_ uiView: MultiSlider, context: UIViewRepresentableContext<MultiSliderSwiftUI>) {

    }
}

class MultiSliderEvents {
    private let valueChanged: ([CGFloat]) -> Void

    init(valueChanged: @escaping ([CGFloat]) -> Void) {
        self.valueChanged = valueChanged
    }

    func addEvents(for slider: MultiSlider) {
        slider.addTarget(self, action: #selector(sliderChanged(_:)), for: .valueChanged)
    }

    @objc func sliderChanged(_ slider: MultiSlider) {
        valueChanged(slider.value)
    }
}
```

In both ways, you can use it `MultiSliderSwiftUI` like, for example, `Button`:

```
MultiSliderSwiftUI { value in
    print("\(value)")
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response! Much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Please try the [MultiValueSlider](https://github.com/yonat/MultiSlider/blob/swiftui/Sources/MultiValueSlider.swift) from the `swiftui` branch and tell me if it works for you.
Example usage: [MultiSliderDemo](https://github.com/yonat/MultiSlider/blob/swiftui/Example/MultiSliderDemo/MultiSliderDemo.swift).

(I'm the package author)

Comment: Thanks for the response! Much appreciated!